# Use a variable defined in another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Range Slider I want to put it in variables with each change and then use it.
In my code this is undefined

My html code is

```
<input id="length" class="border-0" type="range" value="10" min="max="100"/>
```

and my jquery code is

```
$('#length').change(function () {
    length = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val())
});
console.log(length)
```

but it return undefiend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including JQuery library into the script will make it work just fine.

```js
var length;
$('#length').change(function () {
    length = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="length" class="border-0" type="range" value="10" min="max="100"/>
```

Comment: this is ok but i want access to this variable out side this block code